# Is there something like a backtrace to indicate which path a variable has reached to its current value?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have a source like this

```
 //file1.cpp
 int var_1=getDB(" Table_name","column_name");
 ...
 //file2.cpp
 int var2=func2(var_1);
 ...
 //filen.cpp
 int var_n=funcn(var_n_1);
```

In debugging, I first diagnose var_n error message type, but the goal is to modify the table, is there an easy way like backtrace to get to the source of the error, namely the table and field name?

Answer (score 2):

> is there an easy way like backtrace to get to the source of the error, namely the table and field name?

No. There are however reverse debuggers, such as [rr](https://rr-project.org/), which allow you to reverse-step, and reverse-continue. The latter is particularly useful when you want to know when a given variable was last modified.

Comment: Note: plain gdb allows basic reverse debugging as well, but `rr` adds extra goodies.

Comment: As does the current visual studio. S/B a fairly painless process to find the origination. One approach is to set up a trigger each time the variable is changed.